# PhoneGap geolocation() not working in Blackberry simulator?

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, cordova, blackberry-widgets

I installed PhoneGap 0.9.2 and followed the instructions from the PhoneGap wiki page ["Getting Started with PhoneGap (BlackBerry Widgets)"](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-%28BlackBerry-Widgets)
 to run the Phone Gap sample in 9550 BlackBerry simulator.

I used the simulator menu to set a geolocation to a known value.  However, when I click the "Get Location" button in the sample, it prompted the following error message.

> code: 104 message: GPS location acquisition timed out.

Comment: The BlackBerry simulators are notoriously bad for doing geolocation properly... is the 9550 running OS 5 or 6? I would try to get a real device if I were you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the 9800 simulator and that should work. And I should get some stackoverflow points :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to davdjohnson's comments.  I also found the similar complaints on BB's forum.  I switched to 9800 simulator and the geolocation works.